# Error while trying to get max value in array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I was trying to return the max value within an type "T" array list and got an error while using compareTo. This is the full code.

```
package myUtil;

public class SimpleListAry<T extends java.lang.Comparable<T>> extends java.lang.Object implements SimpleList<T> {
    private T[] myList;
    private int size;
    public SimpleListAry(){
       myList = (T[])new Comparable[10];
    }
    public SimpleListAry(int capacity){
        if (capacity <= 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        myList = (T[]) new Object [capacity];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        size = myList.length;
        return size;
    }
    @Override
    public T get(int i) {
        return myList[i];
    }

    @Override
    public T set(int i, T item) {
        return myList[i] = item;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object item) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if (get(i).equals(item)){
                return i;
            }
        }
      return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int at, T item) {
        if (at < 0 || at > size)
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(at);
        for (int i = size; i > at; i--){
            myList[i] = myList [i-1];
        }
//        myList[at] = item;
        size++;
    }


    @Override
    public T remove(int at) {
        if (at < 0 || at >= size)
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(at);
        T item = myList[at];
        for (int i = at; i<size-1; i++)
            myList[i] = myList[i+1];
        size--;
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public T max() {
        T max = myList[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < myList.length; i++){
            if(myList[i].compareTo(max) == 1)
                max = myList[i];
        }
        return max;
    }

    @Override
    public T min() {
        T min = myList[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < size -1; i++){
            if (myList[i].compareTo(min) == -1)
                min = myList[i];
        }
        return min;
    }


}
```

and the error is at Public T max():

```
public T max() {
T max = myList[0];
for (int i = 1; i < myList.length; i++){
    if(myList[i].compareTo(max) == 1)
        max = myList[i];
}
return max;
```

}

I also tried using ">" to compare them but that was not working either. It may be because of the data type but there's no error in the IDE only when I attempt to run it and it points directly to this line in T max(){

```
if(myList[i].compareTo(max) == 1)
```

Comment: Post the error message please.

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at myUtil.SimpleListAry.max(SimpleListAry.java:77)"                                             line 77 points to the myList.compareTo line

Comment: You're confusing the size of your list with the length of the underlying array.

Comment: I changed myList.length to the variable size in the for loop and I still got the same error

Comment: Of course you get the NPE. Your Default-Constructor generates an Array of 10 Callables. Callable is an Interface and no concrete Object. Therefore the call of compareTo() is impossible.

Comment: How should I figure out which of the element are greater than without out using compareTo or ">"?

Comment: @DiabolicWords What Callable? What are you talking about?

Comment: @TobilobaTaiwo If you call the `size()` method your `size` will be wrong too.

Comment: Sorry! Typo. The array contains Comparables and not Callables. But Comparable is just an Interface.

Comment: @DiabolicWords And you can't call methods on an interface?

Comment: @shmosel: No. Except they are static or default methods (or static final interface variables) you can't, because those methods are just abstract rules without a body. You have to implement them into a concrete class. There you can call them. And compareTo is nor static neither default, it's abstract.

Comment: @DiabolicWords What are you saying? Is this not valid code: `Comparable<String> c = "a"; c.compareTo("b");`? How is that different from `myList[i].compareTo(max)`? And what does any of this have to do with a NPE?

Answer (score 1):

Three possibilities of null pointer in `if(myList[i].compareTo(max) == 1)`

1. `myList` - being initialized in constructor, not null
2. `myList[i]` - list initially filled with null !
3. `max`, depending on how `compareTo` is implemented - initialized to `myList[0]`, can be null if list empty

The second case is the problem since the elements of the whole underlying array are being compared without considering the real size of the list.

The `size()` method is wrong since it sets the `size` variable, which is returned, to the length of the array overwriting the correct value.

Just remove the assignment statement inside the `size()` method (and use that method in the comparison loop)